# How do I make a command cooldown for certain discord roles?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So basically, I need to add a cooldown for my discord command but only for certain roles and it has to be a different cooldown for each role. Ex: Members role: 24 hour cooldown for .ping cmd, Subscriber role: 12hour cooldown for .ping cmd.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'pings everyone',
    execute(message, args){
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => ['869682149203271710', '869682285904031764', '869682372231196682'].includes(r.id))) return message.channel.send('You dont have perms to execute this command')
        message.channel.send('@everyone');
            }
        }
```

Basically my cmd only allows 3 roles to use the cmd and I need help adding a different timed cooldown for each role that is allowed to use the cmd. Each role needs to have a different cooldown.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so good approach, but could serve you as a good example how to implement your own cooldown system.

*Why not so good?*

Depends on the usage, if you want a cooldown for a single command. Then this is probably the best way to do it. But if you want to cooldown multiple commands, this is where it loses. Because you would have to copy the cooldown code again and again into each command. Which is really **bad**. The cooldown functionality should be implemented inside of your command handler. With the command only providing the cooldown data such as cooldown times and role ids.
The same goes if you want to restrict the command for specific roles to use. But as I said, it depends on the usage and what you want to do.

```js
const activeCooldowns = new Set();

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Ping everyone.",
    cooldowns: [ // The order is important!
        {
            id: "867559128179671051", // role id
            time: 12 // hours
        },
        {
            id: "862850962758696990", // role id
            time: 24 // hours
        }
    ],
    execute(message, args) {

        // Check if the user has any of the roles to access this command
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => ["867559128179671051", "862850962758696990", "869682372231196682"].includes(role.id))) {
            return message.channel.send("You don't have permissions to execute this command!");
        }

        // Check for an active cooldown
        if (activeCooldowns.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.channel.send("You need to wait before using this command again!");
            return;
        }

        // Execute command
        message.channel.send("@everyone");

        // Get first matching role's cooldown
        const cooldown = this.cooldowns.find((cooldown) => {
            return message.member.roles.cache.has(cooldown.id);
        });

        if (cooldown) { // Check if the role has any cooldown at all
            // Command used, set cooldown
            activeCooldowns.add(message.author.id);
            setTimeout(() => { // Schedule cooldown removal
                activeCooldowns.delete(message.author.id);
            }, cooldown.time * 60 * 60 * 1000); // Convert hours to milliseconds
        }

    }
};
```

*Why is the order of the cooldown array important?*

As users can have multiple roles, what if we have a user, who has both of the roles with cooldowns, which one will win and determine the cooldown? That's when the array order comes in. As the array is searched from the first element to last, we pick up the first match.

You could also determine the user's cooldown only by their highest role. And a plenty of other ways...

Comment: Ok that's really good. I didn't consider the array in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

For example if you wanted a cool down you would need to do this

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'beep',
    description: 'Beep!',
    cooldown: 1, 
    execute(message) {
        message.channel.send('Boop.');
    },
};
```

Comment: yes, but i need it so that each role has a different cooldown.I dont want all roles to have the same cooldown. example: members will have 24h cooldown while Moderators will have a 12 hour cooldown.